# Read a body JSON list with FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

The body of an HTTP PUT request is a JSON list - like this:

```
[item1, item2, item3, ...]
```

I can't change this. (If the root was a JSON object rather than a list there would be no problem.)

Using FastAPI I seem to be unable to access this content in the normal way:

```
@router.put('/data')
def set_data(data: DataModel): # This doesn't work; how do I even declare DataModel?
```

---

I found the following workaround, which seems like a very ugly hack:

```
class DataModel(BaseModel):
    __root__: List[str]


from fastAPI import Request

@router.put('/data')
async def set_data(request: Request): # Get the request object directly
    data = DataModel(__root__=await request.json())
```

This surely can't be the 'approved' way to achieve this. I've scoured the documentation both of FastAPI and pydantic. What am I missing?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Descending from the model perspective to primitives

In FastAPI, you derive from `BaseModel` to describe the data models you send and receive (i.e. FastAPI also parses for you from a body and translates to Python objects). Also, it relies on the modeling and processing from `pydantic`.

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str

class ItemList(BaseModel):
    items: List[Item]

def process_item_list(items: ItemList):
    pass
```

This example would be able to parse JSON like

```
{"items": [{"name": "John"}, {"name": "Mary"}]}
```

In your case - depending on what *shape* your list entries have - you'd also go for proper type modeling, but you want to directly receive and process the list without the JSON dict wrapper around it. You could go for:

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str

def process_item_list(items: List[Item]):
    pass
```

Which is now able to process JSON like:

```
[{"name": "John"}, {"name": "Mary"}]
```

This is probably what you're looking for and the last adaption to take is depending on the shape of your *item** in the list you receive. If it's plain strings, you can also go for:

```
from typing import List

def process_item_list(items: List[str]):
    pass
```

Which could process JSON like

```
["John", "Mary"]
```

I outlined the path from models down to primitives in lists because I think it's worth knowing where this can go if one needs more complexity in the data models.

Comment: I thought I'd tried the above but obviously made some mistake along the way and ruled it out. Many thanks.

Comment: Why don't I just post the last option? Yes, that would seem better, but the API spec says that the entire list is rewritten.

Comment: Nah, that last heading was a question to myself - maybe it's poorly phrased, but I wanted to justify why I went all that way down ;)

Comment: i was trying too return an array without a name,  as below;
class ListItem(baseModel)
List[Item]
somehow it was working on print but cannot output . 
class ListItem(List[Item])
pass
saved my life, thanks man

Comment: results in incorrect type `{items :{"items" :["name" ] } }` which is incorrect. About to try what @bilen mentioned.

Comment: @AkshayHazari, my solution has three different options, you seem to have only picked/tried the first one. Go with the second option and you'll be fine (also see example outputs provided in my answer).

Comment: @jbndlr Can you explain how we can use the function while declaring the API , since it just asks for types or classes