# How to pass in a list of class with FastAPI?

Tags: python, rest, service, fastapi

I want to pass in a list of the class declared in the FastAPI service, something like :

```
@router.post("/predict")
async def predict(json_list: List[my_class])-> dict:
```

And I got exception: `'my_class' object is not subscriptable`

What is the correct way to pass in a list of class with FastAPI?
TIA!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60844846/read-a-body-json-list-with-fastapi) answer your question?

Comment: What is `my_class` defined as? Is it actual Pydantic class? On what line does the exception get raised? It seems like you're trying to access a list index on `my_class`, not on `json_list`?

Comment: M.O. - Thanks for the link. In that way, I need to add many lists. Each for a data column. To make it simple, I even think using a str to pass in json as a str.

Comment: MatsLindh - my_class is as following:


class my_class(BaseModel):
    is_checked: bool   
    longitude: float
    latitude: float

Comment: It seems to be okay, if BaseModel was imported from pydantic and List from typing. Either this is not the line where you got the exception or you just need to save your code before executing it.